# How to integrate killbill billing engine with wso2 API manager?

Tags: wso2-api-manager, billing, killbill

I want to integrate killbill billing engine with WSO2 API manager server. Could you please help me to get this done.

Comment: Did you see [this article](https://kesavantechhub.blogspot.co.uk/2016/12/introducing-wso2-esb-connector-for-kill.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API_REQUEST_SUMMARY table generated in DAS, and send that API level data to killbill billing engine to bill per API. Find more details in the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+API+Monetization+Category+Labels) and this [article](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2016/07/article-enabling-monetization-of-apis-with-wso2-api-manager/).

Comment: This table does not contain subscription tier. How to get this information to pass data to billing engine?